# How, using re.findall (regex) print block of text which will include 'start' and 'end' string?

Tags: python, regex

How to modify below script to include lines starting with 'word1' and 'word3' as below code is printing only 'word2' ?

Desired output:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

Content on the test.txt file:

```
word0
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, re
file = 'test.txt'
with open(file) as fp:
   for result in re.findall('word1(.*?)word3', fp.read(), re.S):
       print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) with [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag:

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
    print re.search('word1(.*?)word3', f.read(), flags=re.DOTALL).group(0)
...     
word1
word2
word3
```

Comment: thank you for you input, your solution will print all three lines, however in 3rd line it will only print 'word3' and skip rest of the line, is there any way of including whole line staring with 'word3'?